# css is linked to .html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, stylesheet

I recently downloaded a theme namely (scalia)
it has lots of css but they are present in file with .html extension
every page of this theme open good at local computer [not localhost (i am directly opening index.html in browser)] but when upload it to hosting it shows a mime type error.

Stylesheets are linked in this format

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='layerslider-group-css' href="indexf67d.html?f=scalia/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/static/css/layersli‌​der.css,scalia/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css,scalia/w‌​p-content/plugins/scalia-style-changer/css/ssc-style.css,scalia/wp-content/plugin‌​s/mailchimp-for-wp/assets/css/checkbox.min.css,scalia/wp-content/themes/scalia/cs‌​s/woocommerce.css,scalia/wp-content/themes/scalia/css/woocommerce1.css" type='text/css' media='all'/>
```

I already got these css file layerslider.css, styles.css, ssc-styles.css etc. etc.

My main question is [is there any alternative of the above code? so that i can replace this code and link my css files manually]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

If you have a .css file in the same directory than your html file, you can include it that way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myfile.css">
```

If it's in another directory, use relative path or complete path like so

Relative: file inside folders that are in the same directory than the html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="folder/anotherfolder/myfile.css">
```

Relative: file that is in the root of the directory containing the html file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../myfile.css">
```

Complete

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/Users/yourname/Documents/CSS/myfile.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just visit the link in your href. Save the CSS that you get as a seperate CSS file. Replace the **href** in the above line with the path to new downloaded file.

Comment: should i find indexf67d.html and change it to something.css or scalia/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/static/css/layersli‌​der.css and link it again

Comment: Not just **indexf67d.html**. Enter domain name + href link and check if you get CSS.

Comment: If you provide me with the link of the theme, I may be able to help.